# New Reputation Method - Possible Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I just noticed what I think is a bug. I answered a question on SO that was more cynical than anything and earned an upvote for it (I was at 190 rep for the day and it took me to 200). I then deleted this post (no reputation loss) and one of my other answers received an upvote, and there it was again +10 more.

I am not sure if I was seeing things, but I'm pretty sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of [the new reputation changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) this will take a maximum of 5 minutes to resolve itself, correcting your reputation to what it should be for all of the votes involved.

Answer (score 3):

> I then deleted this post (no reputation loss) and one of my other answers received an upvote, and there it was again +10 more.

Enjoy those 10 points while you have them.  You'll lose them the next time your rep is recalculated.

Comment: I figured as much, but how often is rep recalculated?

Comment: @Kyle: there's no sitewide scheduled recalcs, at the moment, but a mod can kick off a recalc at anytime.  if you'd like one just flag one of your posts and request it in the textbox.

Comment: @quack - thanks I have done so. :)